# Windows Rstudio 4.1.2 and neo4r_0.1.1 connection problem

Tags: r

Probably my fault but I have Neo4j desktop open and running with an active project in the viewer. This shows as localhost:7687 Create a neo4r con object with correct password as

con <- neo4j_api$new(

- ```
  url = "http://localhost:7687",
  ```
- ```
  user = "neo4j",
  ```
- ```
  password = "xxxx"
  ```
- )

and then

> con$ping()
> [1] 200
> con$get_relationships()

## A tibble: 1 x 1

labels

1 list(oidc_providers = list())

> con$get_version()
> NULL

So the 200 says good boy but the con functions say no. I used powershell as

Test-NetConnection localhost -port 7687
WARNING: TCP connect to (::1 : 7687) failed

ComputerName     : localhost
RemoteAddress    : 127.0.0.1
RemotePort       : 7687
InterfaceAlias   : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
SourceAddress    : 127.0.0.1
TcpTestSucceeded : True

which I think means the port does exist. I would greatly appreciate advice to let me continue with neo4r.

Answer (score 0):

Withdrawn. Similar questions can be found under neo4j tag.